# How to extract angle $0 \le \varphi < 2 \pi$ from a complex number $a + i \, b$?

Tags: complex, trigonometry

Suppose you have a complex number of the standard shape $z = a + i \, b$ (where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers).  How can we convert it to the polar shape $z = A \, e^{i \varphi}$?  More specifically, I would like to get a pair of positive numbers: $A > 0$ and $0 \le \varphi < 2\pi$.

The command `Abs[z]` gives us the amplitude $A > 0$ (a real number).  The command `Arg[z]` gives an angle, but apparently it's not always a positive value: $0 \le \varphi < 2\pi$ (for example: `Arg[-4.20 - 5.86 I] = -2.192`, which is not what I need).  So what should be the simplest way to get an angle $\varphi$ that stays positive, and in the usual anti-clock sense of rotation?

Comment: `Mod[arg, 2 Pi]`?

Comment: From the help of `Arg`: "The result from Arg[z] is always between -\[Pi] and +\[Pi]. ". Therefore, if the result of `Arg` is below zero, you can simply add `2Pi` to get what you want. That is exactly  what Michael proposes by `Mod`.

Comment: @DanielHuber Not really: `Mod[0, 2 Pi]` returns `0`.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher. That's fine,  0 is not below zero.

Comment: @DanielHuber Oh, sorry. I have overlooked that you used an if clause. ^^

Comment: `Arg[z/I]+Pi/2` also works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work (afk)

```
Mod[Arg[z], 2 Pi]
```